# Using reference of Windows.Input for using ICommand in the VM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, uwp

I am working on a UWP application which is based on the MVVM Pattern. for binding the UI actions I am using ICommand in the VM for which I need to provide a reference to Windows.Input .Is It breaking the MVVM.

If I create a class which implements the ICommand interface and use it for command binding then it breaks the rule of "Coding to Interfaces".

```
//This is what i am doing currently

public ICommand command;
command = new RelayCommand();

// I have tried this to remove the reference of windows.input from the VM

public RelayCommand command;
command = new RelayCommand();

//isn't it breaking the rule of coding to interfaces
```

Which approach should I follow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method is correct.

Why are you trying to remove the reference to `System.Windows.Input`? That's just the namespace, the actual project reference is to `System.dll` which is platform-independent.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use x:Bind over RelayCommands for simplicity as long as you've set your view model in the view.cs file you can just bind a handler for the event

SessionView.xaml.cs:

```
Tapped="{x:Bind Path=ViewModel.CancelClick}"
```

SessionView.cs

```
    public SessionViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }
    public SessionView() => this.InitializeComponent();

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        var prms = (WindowParameters)e.Parameter;
        prms.Frame = this.Frame;
        this.ViewModel = new SessionViewModel(prms);
        this.DataContext = ViewModel;
        this.ViewModel.LoadFullModel();
    }
```